# First website: problem with media queries in one section

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to deploy my first website. Unfortunately I have a problem with media queries. I don't know how to style media queries for mobile devices for one of my sections.

```css
.row {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

    .logo-small img {  
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 30%;
            height: 10%;
            padding-top: 30px;
            margin-left: 60px;
        }

    .logo-small-retina {
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: none;
        }

    .main-logo {
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
        }

        .main-logo img{
            width: 15%;
            height: 10%;

        }
        .main-logo-retina{

            display: none;
        }

        .dream-header{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-left: -40px;
        }

        .dream-header img{
            width: 40%;
            height: 10%;
        }

        .dream-header-retina{
            display: none;
        }

        .map{

            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .map-retina{
            display: none;
        }

        .ireland{

            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 65px;
        }

        .ireland img {
            position: relative;
            width: 40%;
            height: 10%;
            margin-top: -4%;
        }

        .ireland-retina{

            display: none;
        }


        .sandra img {
        /*display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 105px;
        margin-top: -50%;
        margin-left: 14%;*/
    }
        .rollOver {
            display: block;
            width: 2%;
            position: relative;
            margin-left: 47.69%;
            margin-top: -22.5%;
        }
        .sandra{
            display: none; 
            position: relative;
            width: 250%;
            margin-top: -790%;
            margin-left: -176%;
}
        }


        .sandra img {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;

        }




        .text-map{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 20%;
            margin-bottom: 5%;
        }

        .text-map img {
            position: relative;
            width: 40%;
            height: 10%;
            display: block;
            margin-top: 24%;
            margin-left: 27%;
            margin-right: 27%;
        }

        .text-map-retina{

            display: none;
        }

.iradio{

    margin-top: 20px;
}
        .iradio-logo{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;

        }
        .iradio-logo-retina{

            display: none;
        }

        .iradio-logo img{
            width: 10%;
            height: 5%; 
        }

        .garry-text{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;

        }

        .garry-text img{
            width: 20%;
            height: 10%;    
        }
        .garry-text-retina{

            display: none;
        }
.garry{
    width: 100%;
    /*margin-top: 20px;*/
}

        .garrybg{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            background: url("../images/garry-bg.png") no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
            text-align: center;

        }
        .centerVideo {
            margin: auto;
            width:33%;
        }
        .garrybg-retina{
            display: none;
        }




.enter{
    width: 100%;
    /*margin-top: 20px;*/
}       
        .enter-text{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;


        }

        .enter-text img{
            width: 10%;
            height: 5%;
            mar
        }

        .enter-text-retina{
            display: none;
        }
.win{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    /*margin-top: 20px;*/
}       
        .chancetowin{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;


        }

        .chancetowin img{
            width: 70%;
            height: 55%;
            mar
        }

        .chancetowin-retina{
            display: none;
        }

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.social-retina{
        display: none;
}

.form-control{

    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn-submit{
        width: 75%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 25px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        display: block;
}

#btn {
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#share{

    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    height: 10%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px; 
}

.player .title{

    display: none;
}

.fb-share-button{
    margin: 4px 10px 0px 10px;
    margin
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.twitter-share-button{
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.footer{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.footer-vid{
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
}

.footer-vid-retina{
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px){

        .container-fluid{
            width: 100%;
        }

        .row{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .header{
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }

        .logo-small{
            display: none;
        }

        .logo-small-retina{
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            padding-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        .main-logo{
            display: none;
        }

        .main-logo-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .main-logo-retina img{
            position: relative;
            width: 150px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-left: 105px;
            margin-right: 105px;
        }

        .dream-header{
            display: none;
        }

        .dream-header-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .dream-header-retina img {
            position: relative;
            width: 318px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-left: 7px;
            margin-right: 7px;
        }

        .map{
            display: none;
        }

        .map-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .ireland{
            display: none;
        }

        .ireland-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .ireland-retina img {
            position: relative;
            width: 318px;
            margin-top: -5px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-left: 7px;
            margin-right: 7px;
        }

        .text-map{
            display: none;
        }

        .text-map-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .text-map-retina img {
            position: relative;
            width: 318px;
            margin-top: 35px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-left: 7px;
            margin-right: 7px;
        }

        .iradio{
            width: 330px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .iradio-logo{
            display: none;
        }

        .iradio-logo-retina{
            display:block;
        }

        .iradio-logo-retina img {
        position: relative;
        width: 40%;
        margin-top: -12px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: 93px;
        margin-right: 69px;
        }

        .garry-text{
            display: none;
        }

        .garry-text-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .garry-text-retina img {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: -31px;
        margin-left: 69px;
        margin-right: 69px;
        }

        .garrybg{
            background: none;
        }

        .centerVideo{
            width: 100%;

        }

    /*  .garrybg-retina{
            display: block; 
            height: 40px;
        }

        .garrybg-retina img {
        position: relative;
        width: 400px;
        margin-top: -246px;
        margin-bottom: -240px;
        margin-left: -23px;
        margin-right: 69px;
        }*/


        #garry-vid-retina{
            margin-left: 117px;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            bottom: -48px;
        }

        .enter-text{
            display: none;
        }

        .enter-text-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .enter-text-retina img {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        margin-top: -136px;
        margin-bottom: -138px;
        margin-left: 65px;
        margin-right: 65px;
        }

        .win {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80%;
        margin-top: 44px;
        padding-top: 50px;
        /* margin-top: 20px; */
        }

        .chancetowin{
            display: none;
        }

        .chancetowin-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .chancetowin-retina img{
            position: relative;
            width: 340px;
            margin-top: -35px;
            margin-left: 6px;
            margin-right: 6px;
        }


        .social{
            display: none;
        }
        .social-retina{
            display:block;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .footer-vid{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            height: 242px;
        }
    }
```

```html
 <section class="contact-us" id="contact">
        <div class="containernew">
            <h2>text</h2>
            <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
           
            <p style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> 312 432 321</p>
            <p><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> @gmail.com</p>
            <div class="contact-box">
                <form action="POST" data-netlify=true netlify name="form">
                    <div class="name-email"><input type="text" placeholder="Imię " name="Imię">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="Email"></div>
                    <div class="subject"><input type="text" placeholder="Temat" name="Temat"></div>
                    <div class="message"><textarea name="Your text" id="" cols="30" rows="10"
                            placeholder="Twoja wiadomość"></textarea></div>
                    <button>Wyślij wiadomość</button>
                    <div data-netlify-recaptcha ></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I tried to style `.containernew` why media queries but `width` and `max-width` seem to not work somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you could put your code through the W3C validator https://validator.w3.org/

There are several problems in the CSS given in the question such as a spurious right brace, plus some ‘floating’ declarations that are not terminated properly, e.g. `margin`

If you still have problems when these errors are removed, put a snippet into your question which shows the problem you are having and we can have another look.